# Naming convention for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If I have a company, xyz, with a domain name, xyz.com, I would have a tenant, xyz.onmicrosoft.com. My AD for employees would be xyz. What would I typically name my B2C tenant? It can't be xyz, correct? What have others done?

**UPDATE**
In looking at examples I saw a reference to contosob2c, and it seemed to make sense to me as a good approach. In my example xyz would be the AD domain/directory/tenant for employees (xyz.onmicrosoft.com) and I would create a B2C directory as xyzb2c for customers (xyzb2c.onmicrosoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

You determine what your audience (customers) would deem sensible, since they will authenticate at xyz.b2clogin.com.

Comment: I have a different B2C tenant and it says xyzalpha.onmicrosoft.com. When I registered my domain, I saw the xyx.onmicrosoft.com as a directory listed under my account (upper right, switch directory). I also cannot create a new B2C tenant with xyz because "already in use by another directory". It would make sense if b2c were completely different, like xyz.b2clogin.com, but they seem to use onmicrosoft.com. So there seems to be now way to use xyz for both the purpose of a b2c login and for a directory.

Comment: The authentication endpoint provisioned for your directory, is tied/related to the directories initial domain name. No way around it. You cannot create xyz.onmicrosoft.com, and then use xyz.b2clogin.com against abc.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: There is no way to specify the b2clogin during creation of a B2C directory so you have to come up with different name. I saw an example (as stated in my update) of contosob2c, so it seems like that is the way to go. I believe you can't refuse an AD name for B2C as they both end up being onmicrosoft.com.